# How to select a column from another table by using DB::raw when it has a polymorphic relationships in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, polymorphism

I have 3 tables structure like below:-

> stock_purchases

| id | entity_type | entity_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | App\Models\Supplier | 1 |
| 2 | App\Models\Company | 1 |

> suppliers

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Supplier A |
| 2 | Supplier B |

> companies

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A |
| 2 | Company B |

I need to output entity_name in my stock purchase index page, so the expected result will looks like this

**Expected Result**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Supplier A |
| 2 | Company A |

for some reason i don't want to use $stockPurchase->relation->name, i want to output the name like this $stockPurchase->entity_name so i need to get it done when i run the query, below is my current code:-

```
$model->newQuery()
        ->select([
            'stock_purchases.*',
            DB::raw("(CASE 
            WHEN entity_type = 'App\Models\Supplier' THEN suppliers.name
            WHEN entity_type = 'App\Models\Company' THEN companies.name
            ELSE 'Something went wrong'
            END) AS entity_name"),
        ])
        ->leftJoin('suppliers', function($join){
            $join->on('suppliers.id', '=', 'stock_purchases.entity_id')
            ->where('stock_purchases.entity_type', Supplier::class);
        })
        ->leftJoin('companies', function($join){
            $join->on('companies.id', '=', 'stock_purchases.entity_id')
            ->where('stock_purchases.entity_type', Company::class);
        })
        ->get();
```

So far i found 2 problems in this query:-

`WHEN entity_type = 'App\Models\Supplier'` this part always not match so i will always get 'Something went wrong' as output i think is because of the slash even i use double slash also get the same result

`THEN suppliers.name` this part always return empty, it cant get column from another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using 3 slashes `App\\\Models\\\Supplier`, is working now but i still don't know why

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with two backslashes, I think it's because SQL treats the backslash as an escape character:

To use in SQL

> select *
> from invoice_lines
> where invoiceable_type != 'App\\Models\\Payment';

Laravel 3 backslashes as mentioned in the previous comments